# How to check if event occurred after clicking on a button

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, addeventlistener

I have the following HTML table format (just showing one row out of many)  which has a button on the last cell:

```html
<div id=main>
     <div class='info'>
        <p>Name: <span class='x'>ABC</span></p>
        <p>Number: <span class='x'>0</span></p>
        <table class='newTable'>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Number
                </th>
                <th>    
                    Value
                </th>
                <th>    
                    Go
                </th>
                
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    0
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class='k'>11.7</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class='go'>Go</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have an eventListener (`mainEntries.addEventListener('click', clickFunction)`) which triggers whenever inside `<div id = main> ... </div>`

I am not allowed to change the HTML. I have two questions:

1. How do I check inside `function clickFunction(e)` if I clicked on the button "GO" or somewhere inside `<div id = main> ... </div>`

***inside `clickFunction(e)` e is the `MouseEvent`

2. If I click on the button how can I get the text inside first cell of the same row?

Comment: this phenomenon is called event delegation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already was mentioned, you can use `e.target` to get clicked element. Then, you can use combination of [`closest()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/closest) and [`cells.item()`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/coll_table_cells.asp) functions of the found button:

```js
const mainEntries = document.querySelector('#main');

const clickFunction = e => {
  if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON' && e.target.classList.contains('go')) {
    const firstCellSameRow = e.target.closest('tr').cells.item(0).innerText;
    console.log('GO button clicked. First cell\'s text at the same row is ', firstCellSameRow);
  }
  else {
    console.log('Main div clicked outside of GO button');
  }
}

mainEntries.addEventListener('click', clickFunction);
```

```html
<div id=main>
     <div class='info'>
        <p>Name: <span class='x'>ABC</span></p>
        <p>Number: <span class='x'>0</span></p>
        <table class='newTable'>
            <tr>
                <th>
                    Number
                </th>
                <th>    
                    Value
                </th>
                <th>    
                    Go
                </th>

            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    0
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class='k'>11.7</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class='go'>Go</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    2
                </td>
                <td>
                    <span class='k'>8.5</span>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <button class='go'>Go</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

I added another distinct row for showing different logs.

Answer (score 1):

1) you should consider `e.target` inside `function clickFunction(e)`

2) you should select the grandparent of that button, then, from the parent, you select the first child. `buttonElement.parentNode.parentNode.children[0].innerText`